# Errno 28 Low on disk space

Tags: amazon-web-services, jupyter-notebook, amazon-sagemaker

I am trying to install a python package in aws notebook, instance g4dn.xlarge. The package itself is 3GB. The package doesnt install and I am getting this error errno 28 low on disk space. I even increased the volume size up till 50GB. But the error still persists.
Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

Increasing the volume size is not enough. You have to manually **extend your partition** as well. The process is described in detail in [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/recognize-expanded-volume-linux.html).